# Add css to a dynamic added Tablerow

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a Website using jquery mobile and on that website I got a table that looks like this: 
 
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ctc3j0Lu/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow gk-decorate" id="testTable" is="jqm-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="1">Animal</th>
      <th data-priority="1">Sports</th>
      <th data-priority="1">Names</th>
      <th data-priority="1">Fruits</th>
      <th data-priority="1">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Cat</th>
      <td>Football</td>
      <td>Anna</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Dog</th>
      <td>Baseball</td>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Checked</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Shark</th>
      <td>Hockey</td>
      <td>David</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Checked</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ape</th>
      <td>PingPong</td>
      <td>Locke</td>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My question is: Can I somehow add a css class or css in general to the rows that got the String `"Checked"` inside the `Status Coloumn`.
I tried stuff like that:

```
var qTable = document.getElementById("testTable");
var row = qTable.tBodies[0].insertRow();
row.addClass() //error does not support addClass
row.css({..})//error does not support css..
```

> NOTE: The table content gets added Dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains:` pseudo selector to filter out `<td>`s with your marker and then get their parent node (`<tr>`s)

```
$('td').filter(":contains('Checked')").parent().addClass('sugar')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rttmq4we/

Answer (score 1):

try this,

JS

```
$("#testTable td").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() =='StatusChecked'){
   $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
   }
});
```

CSS (for testing style only)

```
.checked{
  background:green;
}
```

updated fiddle  -

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/erc3ujzw/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#testTable tr").each(function(){
  var tds  = $(this).find("td");
  var statusCell = $(tds[3]);
  var statusCellTxt = statusCell.text();
  if (statusCellTxt.indexOf('Checked') !== -1){
    $(statusCell).css('border', '1px solid red');
  }
});
```

See fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ctc3j0Lu/4/).